# Mach's Principle as an initial value problem?

Tags: general-relativity, machs-principle

So in this fascinating interview Abhay Ashtektar [claims](https://youtu.be/03ReIvXKrrU) there is a technical formulation of Mach's principle as an initial value problem.

At 1:44:22

> and the main point is that the only way to formulate it (Mach's  principle) is something
> and that I don't get want to get into. It's technical but basically
> again in terms of this initial value formulation that we talked about

What is this formulation?

Comment: It might be related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/463574/is-mtws-argument-in-favor-of-machs-principle-valid).

Comment: This interview is 3.5+ hours long. Maybe you could provide time marker of the relevant part, or/and transcribe this part in more details.

Comment: @A.V.S. done :)